# Use Bourbon with Bitters and Neat

Tags: frameworks, sass, bourbon, neat

I want to use Bourbon with Neat and Bitters for my next project. I have installed all three but I have no idea how to proceed.

Do I use the three folders separately in my project folder or do I need to add the different imports to _bourbon.scss so I have all imports in one main file?

For instance, there are button.scss, clearfix.scss and hide-text.scss in the Bourbon (in addons) and Bitters (in extends) folder, aren't these going to conflict when used together?

All help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 7):

You have to import the files of the plugins (bourbon, neat and bitters) into one main file. Button.scss, clearfix.scss and hide-text.scss won´t conflict.

This is how I organize the project that im currently working on:

```
- project
|--css
      |--base //(Bitters)
      |--bourbon
      |--neat
      |--application.sass
      |--application.css
|--js
|--img
|--index.html
```

In application.sass this is my initial code:

```
@import 'bourbon/bourbon'
@import 'base/base'
@import 'neat/neat'
```

So I import Bourbon, Bitters and Neat in my main .sass file so I can easily start using them. You can start changing the default settings in base/_variables.scss

Check this video for more info: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ItNE_DX6Cc

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be better to summarise the contents of the video here, so that the solution is here for future readers (The video could be taken down or be inaccessible in the future). Leaving your answer as-is might risk it being closed as a link-only answer.

Comment: I have found that video and it worked. Until I started working in the framework and Codekit compiled it and gave me loads of errors. Still working my way around that those!

Comment: Thanks @GenericJon for the advice, i will edit the answer right now.